# Should we be nicer when dupehammering?

Tags: discussion, dupehammer, canonical

We all know the situation, someone posts a [`NullPointerException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) or [unresolved external](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) question and the dupehammer falls in short order.

Now, these canonical questions have ten or fifteen answers to choose from, so either we take the "Teach a Man to Fish" attitude and leave them to either dredge through the list or go off in the huff and never visit SO again, or we can take an extra 10 seconds to find the specific answer and add a comment pointing them to it.

I try to do the second whenever I see an over-eager dupehammer, and I would like to see others doing the same. What is the official stance on this?

Comment: Many times, especially with very common canonical, instead of you spending an extra 10 seconds OP could have easily spent 5 seconds researching and finding the duplicate/answer.

Comment: how do you know it'll take 10 second to find *the one* answer and not a few minutes giving them answer after answer after answer with the OP rejecting each one because *"it doesn't work"*. at best pointing to the dup question the OP will see the accepted answer and if it doesn't work they'll look at the rest themselves finding the one that works for them

Comment: I though dupehammering was nice in and of itself. It lets the experts in a tag get the questioner their answer faster than if they had to wait until 5 people all chose to close.

Answer (score 9):

#### There is nothing *un-nice* about not leaving a comment!

> It is not *mean*, or *rude* or *not nice* to not leave a comment. The
> close reason says it all. Leaving a comment just begs for extended
> discussion for you to spoon feed them an explanation and turns into a
> *real time debugging session in the comments* which is not what the comments are for. Comments on down votes, close votes are never
> constructive in the aggregate.

Since you put up the straw man of `NullPointerException` the canonical is all you need to dupe with. Because every `NullPointerException` is caused by the **exact same thing**. Now the solution on how to prevent that is extremely localized in almost every case. And in those cases 10 seconds of using a step debugger will show exactly how to fix the problem.

Same goes with `NoClassDefFoundError` and `FileNotFoundException` and the same things exist in [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) with `Undefined` methods and attributes. They are all caused by the same thing but have extremely localized fixes, which can always be solved quickly with a step debugger.

There is no reasonable way to debug someones **environment** from StackOverflow.

If there is a hint of what is wrong in the code is going to be closed because of a Typo/Unreproducible anyway.

These extremely common exceptions/error messages can be resolved with minimal searching and reading of documentation and a few seconds of setting break points in a step debugger.

Adding yet another extremely localized explanation of these types of questions actually makes the problem **worse** because it just generates more answers that do no one any good except the OP for that specific line of code. They will just come back in 5 mins or less asking the exact same thing on the next `NPE`.

These questions always qualify for a down vote as well per the reasoning under the arrow. *This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*

The dupe to a canonical makes the site better in every way.